# How to order exact words in solr response

Tags: apache, solr

I have indexed my data in Solr using N-GramsFilter.The problem I am facing is that it returns all document that contains word as a substring.. Like I searched for DHA in my data...
It returns

```
DHAND
DHARD 
DHAI 
DHAM
DHA
```

The DHA is at number 5 I want it to be first one as it exactly matches the term user searching for. How can I order my response so that the exact matching documents should come first followed by partially matched document....

Secondly My data contains non English words but they are spelled in English Can I use the spell checker comes with solr.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to copyField and search both fields but with different boosts. So, you put the very high boost on the field that is processed to give you exact matches only. If it matches, that document goes first; if not - more relaxed n-gram field.

I don't understand the second half of the question (non-English, but spelt in English). It should probably be a separate question with more details/examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here you may need to have another field same as you are searching on.

And the new copied field should be of type String and can be used for the sorting.

The field you are using now for the sorting is been tokenized and cannot give you proper sorting.

```
1. Create/add another field by using copy field 

<copyField source="reference" dest="referenceSort"/>

2. Add the field like below.

<field name="referenceSort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Please refer the documentation [Documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort)

> Sorting can be done on the "score" of the document, or on any
>   multiValued="false" indexed="true" field provided that field is either
>   non-tokenized (ie: has no Analyzer) or uses an Analyzer that only
>   produces a single Term (ie: uses the KeywordTokenizer)